# How to format a table in an Excel macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to format a table from one format to another utilizing a macro.  Please see below for an example of what I am trying to do.

```
From this:
User_ID  FNAME    LNAME   ROLE_ID
1          Bob      Smith   Role1
1          Bob      Smith   Role2
1          Bob      Smith   Role2.2
```

To this

```
User_ID FNAME  LNAME   ROLE_ID   ROLE_ID2
1         Bob   Smith   Role1    Role2, Role2.2
```

So I have 5 different "role categories".  For example, A, B, C, D are my categories. Each category can have multiple roles assigned to a user.  I want to have 5 static columns that list the different role categories and what the user is assigned from each.

If this is possible, it would be helpful to understand where to start.

Comment: For some reason the formatting messed up above --                                                      I would like do go from User_ID FNAME LNAME ROLE_ID where a user is listed multiple times to one row for the user where it looks something like this User ID FNAME LNAME ROLE_ID ROLE_ID2 where ROLE ID and ROLE ID 2 are categories

Comment: You could start by searching SO for other examples of that kind of problem. It has been asked and answered here in the past.

Comment: In addition to what @RonRosenfeld suggested, please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question. Without showing your coding attempts and where they are failing, you'll likely not get much help as SO is not "code for me" site.

Comment: You can use a pivot table for this.